# Pyspark DataFrame Function

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

The problem I was having is trying to convert the following code in Python to PySpark. I'm extremely new to PySpark but I have a column of float data and for each row I want to perform a calculation based on the floor function value of the data input into the row. I want to add the discounted values for every year leading up to the 'ExpirationPeriod' and output this value into a new 'output' column. This is my Python code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ExpirationPeriod':[1.2,2.0,3.0,4.5]})

def sum_data(row):
    return sum([100/1.02**i + 5 for i in range(int(row['ExpirationPeriod']))])

df['output'] = df.apply(sum_data, axis=1)
```

And this is what my attempt in PySpark looks like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct, col
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, DoubleType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1.2, ),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
     (2.0, ),
     (3.0, ),
     (4.5, )],
    ["ExpirationPeriod"])

function = udf(lambda row: [sum([i for i in range(x)]) for x in row], DoubleType())

df = df.withColumn("Counts", df["ExpirationPeriod"].cast(IntegerType()))
new_df = df.withColumn("new", function(struct([df['Counts']])))

new_df.show()
```

I'm not sure what's not working with my code or what I might have to change to mirror my code in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `sum_data` that work in `Pandas` directly in Spark with minor change even without using `Pandas` API in `Spark`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct, col
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, DoubleType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1.2, ),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
     (2.0, ),
     (3.0, ),
     (4.5, )],
    ["ExpirationPeriod"])

@udf(returnType=DoubleType())
def sum_data(row):
    return sum([100/1.02**i + 5 for i in range(row)])

df = df.withColumn("Counts", df["ExpirationPeriod"].cast(IntegerType()))
new_df = df.withColumn("new", sum_data(col('counts')))

new_df.show()
+----------------+------+------------------+
|ExpirationPeriod|Counts|               new|
+----------------+------+------------------+
|             1.2|     1|             105.0|
|             2.0|     2| 208.0392156862745|
|             3.0|     3|309.15609381007306|
|             4.5|     4| 408.3883272647775|
+----------------+------+------------------+
```

There are two reasons why your Spark code is not working:

1. Passing `struct([df['Counts']])` in your UDF: You only need to pass the required column, which is `Counts`, into your UDF. Therefore, only `col('Counts')` is needed.
2. When you're using UDF in Spark, `for x in row` is not worked since the value you passed is a integer.

---

Edit 1 on 2023-04-07

Decorator itself doesn't have any impact to your function, as it's just a design patten and provide a wrapping to your `sum_data` function. If I use your coding style it should be like:

```
new_df = df.withColumn(
    "new",
    func.udf(lambda row: sum([100/1.02**i + 5 for i in range(row)]), returnType=DoubleType())(func.col('counts'))
)
```

The real impact to your `sum_data` is the `func.udf`. Since Spark dataframe is a JVM structure and your function is implemented by Python. In order to process your logic, which is designed in Python language, serialization and deserialization is needed to move the data. Therefore, `func.udf` is needed when you want to perform customized transformation to your data in Spark dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! That works great, just a quick question. I know "@udf(returnType=DoubleType())" is a decorator function. How is the functionality of my function changed using this decorator?

Comment: @MikeP. I have updated my answer. Let me know if it can answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it very clear, I still prefer your solution as it's much cleaner but it makes sense why that is needed now